# Remove Kernel Extension which causes kernel panic after migration to other mac

Tags: macos, kernel, osx-mavericks, macos-big-sur, kernel-extension

I migrated my mac book pro to a mac mini. Right now I have a kernel panic at each startup. Booting with safe mode works and I identified that the kernel extension `com.eltima.eveusb.kext.controller` causes the problem. It is coming from the application  [USB Network Gate for Mac](http://wiki.eltima.com/user-guides/usb-mac.html) which I unfortunately installed once to test it.

I already searched for the Kernel Extension in `/System/Library/Extensions` but could not find any matching extension there.

How can I remove this extension (as said, the application itself is already uninstalled).

Below I attached some parts of the kernel panic report.

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f8e2ba000->0xffffff7f8e2e2fff
     com.eltima.eveusb.kext.controller(2.0)[1C357F99-D355-3B55-890B-96E70B8231B1]@0xffffff7f8fa57000->0xffffff7f8fa74fff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily(650.4.4)[972D3024-AF9C-3E09-A9EC-D9AB2A559B38]@0xffffff7f8e743000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f8e2ba000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient(650.4.4)[FC4B241E-C861-3821-B0D0-03DD648D8D9A]@0xffffff7f8e7c2000

...
System uptime in nanoseconds: 62692972204
last loaded kext at 62359499086: com.eltima.eveusb.kext.controller  2.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8fa57000, size 122880)
loaded kexts:
com.eltima.eveusb.kext.controller   2.0.0
com.eltima.eveusb.kext.arbiter  2.0.0
com.shapeservices.msm.driver.MSMFramebuffer 3.3.2
com.shapeservices.msm.driver.MSMVideoDevice 3.3.2
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.11
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.0.9d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.5.3fc1
...
```

Comment: I had a similar issue after update to Big Sur: stuck in a reboot loop. Only safe mode was possible. Fortunately apple kernel panic said: the extension `us.electronic.kext.vusb` panics. The process name corresponding to this panic thread is "eveusbd".  The solution of l'L'l works :-).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the script below as eveusb_uninstall.sh, then open terminal an type:

```
sudo sh eveusb_uninstall.sh
```

eveusb_uninstall.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if test -f "/Library/Application Support/Eltima/eveusbd/bin/uninstall"
then
    echo "eveusb: uninstalling USB To Ethernet Connector 1.x"
    /Library/Application\ Support/Eltima/eveusbd/bin/uninstall || true
fi

if test -f "/Library/Frameworks/EveUSB.framework/Support/uninstall"
then
    echo "eveusb: uninstalling USB Network Gate 2.x"
    /Library/Frameworks/EveUSB.framework/Support/uninstall || true
fi

COUNTER=0

while true; do
    DAEMONS=`ps ax | grep -v grep | grep -c eveusbd`

    if test $DAEMONS -gt 0; then
        echo "eveusb: trying to terminate daemon"

        launchctl remove com.eltima.eveusbd || launchctl remove com.eltima.eveusb.daemon || killall -u root -c eveusbd || true

        let COUNTER=COUNTER+1

        if test $COUNTER -eq 10; then
            echo "eveusb: killing daemon"
            killall -u root -c eveusbd -KILL
        fi

        if test $COUNTER -gt 10; then
            echo "eveusb: cant stop daemon"
            break
        fi

        sleep 1
    else
        break
    fi
done

if test -d "/Library/Application Support/Eltima/eveusbd"
then
    echo "eveusb: clearing old configuratiins"
    rm -fr "/Library/Application Support/Eltima/eveusbd"
fi

if test -f "/var/log/eveusbd.log"
then
    echo "eveusb: clearing old log file"
    rm -fr "/var/log/eveusbd.log"
fi

if test -f "/var/log/com.eltima.eveusb.daemon.log"
then
    echo "eveusb: clearing log file"
    rm -fr "/var/log/com.eltima.eveusb.daemon.log"
fi

rm -fr /var/tmp/com.eltima.eveusbd
```

Comment: The solution for me was to look in `/Library/Application Support/` in addition to the usual places for kernel extensions. You might want to point that out for others!

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look in `/Library/Extensions` as well, which is where 3rd party extensions are supposed to go.